# Trouble outputting variant from within foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

Using PHP, I am setting up a variant within a `foreach` loop, and am having trouble outputting it. In the example below, I am only outputting one `$variant`, when there are actually 3 in the `$variantData` variable. How can I loop through each `$variant` and output them?

```
// Loop to find each variants ID
<? foreach ($variantsData as $variantData) {

    $variant = array(
        'id'            => $variantData['variation_id'],
    );
} ?>

// Output each variants ID
<? print_r( $variant['id'] ) ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `[]` to append array. You're just overwriting `$variant` variable every time within the `foreach()` loop. That is the reason you're only outputting one `$variant`, when there are actually 3 in the $`variantData` variable.

```
// Loop to find each variants ID
<? foreach ($variantsData as $variantData) {
    $variant[] = array('id'=> $variantData['variation_id']); // see this line
          //^^
   // Output each variants ID
   print_r($variant);
} ?>

// Output all variants ID
<? print_r( $variant) ?>
```

Now to access specific variant id you've to use the index also e.g to get first variant id, you can use,

```
print_r($variant[0]['id']);
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/Wf9TE

**To get all the variant id's at once, you can do this.**

```
<? foreach ($variantsData as $variantData) {
    // Output each variants ID
    echo $variantData['variation_id'];
    $variant[] = $variantData['variation_id']; // see this line
} ?>

// Output all variants ID
<? print_r( $variant) ?>
```

**To get each variant id inside foreach() loop**

```
<? foreach ($variantsData as $variantData) {
    $variant = $variantData['variation_id']; // see this line
    // Output each variants ID
    echo $variant;
} ?>
```

Comment: No, as `$variant` will contain indexed values: `$variant[0]['id']`, `$variant[1]['id']` and `$variant[2]['id']`

Comment: Afraid this doesn't work. I just get a blank output

Comment: @dungey_140 have a look on my edit again, hope this time you'll understand what I mean, Thanks mate :) best of luck

Comment: Thanks for this, however I want to avoid using something like $variant[0]['id'] as it target just one item, I just want to literally list out all of the 3 $variant IDs?

Comment: @dungey_140 I've **EDITED** again my answer as per your comment, Have a look again :)

Comment: Thanks for this. Whilst this does work to output the IDs directly, I've obviously already setup an array called $variant within a previous foreach loop. I want to access this array, as I've setup a lot more data than just ID, so using your approach would give me a lot of code and repetition. Can I just access $variant, but for each of the items in $VariantsData?

Comment: @dungey_140 Re-check my edit, `echo $variant;` will print each $variant value

Comment: We're not on the same page unfortunately. I want to output $variant['id'] rather than echo-ing $variantData['variation_id']; as this will get very long and cumbersome for the amount of items I have in the arrays. Surely because I've already got this array setup, it should be easy to just loop through and echo the existing array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196653/discussion-between-always-sunny-and-dungey-140).